# Regex match group with elements in random order

Tags: regex, random, regex-group

For simplicity sake, let's say I have the following literal string:

```
abc[4;?;z;*]def
```

where 4, ?, z and * **can appear in random order**, are separated by a ; , and are characters (or strings) that i know beforehand.

I have this regex that matches the string using 'or' groups:

```
abc\[(?:z|\*|4|\?|\;)+\]def
```

The problem is that is still matching if one of the elements is missing in the string, and I want to check if all are present:

```
abc[?;z;*]def
```

Capturing groups are irrelevant for me. I just want to confirm the whole string.

Comment: `abc\[(?=[^][]*z)(?=[^][]*4)(?=[^][]*\?)(?=[^][]*;)(?=[^][]*\*)[z*4?;]+]def` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLLv6F/1))?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the edited version works perfectly. Now I have to study what [^][]* does and why do I need the final [z*4?;]+ .

Comment: Also, the last ] should be escaped, just in case...

Comment: It should only be escaped if you code in MSVC C++ or Ruby, but in Ruby, `[^][]*` does not work, it must be `[^\]\[]*`. What is your programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
abc\[(?=[^][]*z)(?=[^][]*4)(?=[^][]*\?)(?=[^][]*;)(?=[^][]*\*)[z*4?;]+]def
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLLv6F/1). Details:

- `abc\[` - a literal `abc[` string
- `(?=[^][]*z)` - after zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, there must be a `z`
- `(?=[^][]*4)` - after zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, there must be a `4`
- `(?=[^][]*\?)` - after zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, there must be a `?`
- `(?=[^][]*;)` - after zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, there must be a `;`
- `(?=[^][]*\*)` - after zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, there must be a `*`
- `[z*4?;]+` - one or more chars in the set, `z`, `*`, `4`, `?`, `;`
- `]def` - a literal `]def` string.

Comment: Now I start getting it. With escapes is more evident: `[^\]\[]` Or heving them switched: `[^[]]`since order is not relevant. Until now, I thought that `[^]` does one thing and `[]` does another. 
I would even say that the opening square brackets in the exclude list is not needed, `[^\]]`. 

And since the lookeahead groups `(?=...)`don't consume characters (character index is not increasead), I need the last `[z*4?]+` element to advance all characters. I have escaped them all `\Q..\E` since in real script those chars are path strings. Script is Perl, BTW. 

Thank you!

Comment: @androias Escaping depends on the regex library. `[^[]]` is a corrupt pattern.

Comment: accepted answer and edited my above response with details.   I didn't tried the `[^[]]`, so thanks for the heads-up.